# How are some channels creating Minecraft 'Timelapse' videos, pausing gameplay yet moving the camera?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, recording

First of all, the question is going to be really specific and not a duplicate of anything. I know that many people want to know how to record Minecraft gameplay but that not the question here.

I tried to make timelapse videos using some mods but this method makes it really hard to post edit the video or time the commentary correctly.

While watching this video on YouTube, I noticed that the camera kept moving while the game world was frozen.

So, my guess is that, somehow, he managed to record the activity in the game world instead of a video with the camera moving around while he was building. That is really helpfull for editing the video and not have to really worry about correctly timing the commentary and the camera movements before the build itself.

Does anyone know how he was doing that?

Comment: The video linked appears to be using [The Replay Mod](https://www.replaymod.com/)

Comment: Skylinerw, thanks for the edit but I rolled it back. I wanted to link the video at a specific time and by making it a link, it starts the video from the beginning. So it was on purpose.

Comment: colorfusion, I checked out the replay mod, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess [PixelCam](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2327429-pixelcam-camera-studio-for-minecraft-1-8-and-1-9)'s what you're looking for.